# Allocate memory to char *** in C

Tags: c, string, memory, memory-management, matrix

So, I'm having trouble in allocating memory for a `char ***` type variable. My objective is to create a matrix of strings and the code I currently have for memory allocation is the following:

```
char ***matrix;

matrix = calloc(n*MAX_STR, sizeof(char**));
for(z = 0; z < n; z++) {
    matrix[z] = calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_STR; i++) {
        matrix[z][i] = calloc(MAX_STR, sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

I have successfully allocated memory for an array of strings, using this:

```
char **list;
list = calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
list[j] = calloc(MAX_STR, sizeof(char));
}
```

but I'm now having problems with the matrix.

Running the program with --leak-check=full on Valgrind gives me the following message:

```
==5126== Invalid write of size 8
==5126==    at 0x400B9F: createmat (proj.c:100)
==5126==    by 0x401598: main (proj.c:237)
==5126==  Address 0x5210878 is 0 bytes after a block of size 72 alloc'd
==5126==    at 0x4C2ABB4: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==5126==    by 0x400B52: createmat (proj.c:98)
==5126==    by 0x401598: main (proj.c:237)
```

I'd like to figure out out to allocate memory for this, since I'm still a beginner when it comes to memory management in C. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
The matrix is supposed to store n arrays of strings, which correspond to the lines of the input (it's read with `fgets` later), and each array allocates whichever number of words the line has, with each word (read, each string) having at max a `MAX_STR` number of characters.
`n` is a variable read from the input, while `MAX_STR` is a constant defined in the program.

Comment: There's not much point in using `calloc` rather than `malloc`. `calloc` initializes the allocated space to all-bits-zero. This is *not* guaranteed to be the representation of a null pointer (though it commonly is). Suggestion: just use `malloc`, and be careful not to refer to the value of any pointer that you haven't explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to allocate storage for `n` arrays, each with `n` strings, each up to `MAX_STR` long, there are a couple of mistakes in the code

```
matrix = calloc(n*MAX_STR, sizeof(char**));
```

should be

```
matrix = calloc(n, sizeof(char**));
```

and

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX_STR; i++) {
```

should be

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

In a little more detail,

```
matrix = calloc(n*MAX_STR, sizeof(char**));
for(z = 0; z < n; z++) {
```

seems wrong.  You allocate `n*MAX_STR` elements but only use `n` of them

```
matrix[z] = calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < MAX_STR; i++) {
```

is also questionable and is wrong for `n<MAX_STR`.  (You allocate `n` elements then write to `MAX_STR` of them.)

Finally, depending on whether you consider `MAX_STR` to include space for a null terminator, you may need to change

```
matrix[z][i] = calloc(MAX_STR, sizeof(char));
```

to

```
matrix[z][i] = calloc(MAX_STR+1, 1);
```

Comment: `n` is the number of lines from the input while `MAX_STR` is the number of characters allowed in a line. So basically, the second dimension of the matrix would have a max lenght of `MAX_STR`, being that it's supposedly divided by words inside it. So I don't really get why I should change the loop condition.

Comment: I want to allocate `n` arrays, each with an arbitrary number of strings and each with up to `MAX_STR` length. (and thanks for your help so far)

Comment: @Dusk252 I'm not sure I follow.  If my ...more detail... section doesn't help, can you update your question to say exactly what you're trying to store please

Comment: Your second comment overlapped my question and helped clarify things for me.  I think my suggested changes do what you want.  Can you give them a try please?  The second change is probably key.

Answer (score 7):

**Matrix of String or/ 3D char array:**

Suppose you need `N` matrices, each matrix can store `R` strings of **length** `MAX_STR-1` then you should allocated memory your loop as follows, like:

```
char ***matrix;

matrix = calloc(N, sizeof(char**)); 
for(z = 0; z < N; z++) { 
    matrix[z] = calloc(R, sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        matrix[z][i] = calloc(MAX_STR, sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Its will create matrix like:

```
matrix
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| 0                 | 1                | 2                     |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------+        
 |                           |                        |
 ▼                           ▼                        ▼
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|0 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |0 +---►| MAX_STR  |     |0 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|1 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |1 +---►| MAX_STR  |     |1 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|2 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |2 +---►| MAX_STR  |*    |2 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|3 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |3 +---►| MAX_STR  |     |3 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|4 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |4 +---►| MAX_STR  |     |4 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|5 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |5 +---►| MAX_STR  |     |5 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|6 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |6 +---►| MAX_STR  |     |6 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
|7 +---►| MAX_STR  |       |7 +---►| MAX_STR  |     |7 +---►| MAX_STR  |
+--+    +----------+       +--+    +----------+     +--+    +----------+
 ^        ^ 
 |        |
 |        matrix[z][i]
 matrix[z]
```

Here N = 3, and
     R = 8

Its char 3D array of size `matrix[N][R][MAX_STR]`

Suppose, if someone wants to printf string I marked `*` in diagram, that is third string in second array, then he/she need to index like

```
printf("%s",matrix[1][2]);
```

<sub>Although answer is accepted I am updating my answer so onw can find it helpful in future</sub>

Answer (score 2):

As you have said, you were able to successfully create an array of strings using your below code:

```
char **list;
list = calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
list[j] = calloc(MAX_STR, sizeof(char));
}
```

Now, you need an array of array of strings, so it should be:

```
char ***matrix;

matrix = calloc(n, sizeof(char**)); //This creates space for storing the address of 'n' array of strings 
for(z = 0; z < n; z++) { //This loop creates the 'n' array of strings.
    matrix[z] = calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[z][i] = calloc(MAX_STR, sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

So, basically, in the second code, you are just creating space for storing 'n' lists. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: This was an helpful answer as well. Thank you.