# Dynamic pointing array to a dynamic 2 dimensions array?

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc

I need to allocate a char** array that points to a 2 dimensions chars array.

Eventually, I want to point to a "cell" like `players[playerNum][Row][Col]`.
This is what I wrote so far, but it fails.
It is hard to understand the logic behind it, so if you can explain me whats wrong it will be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int numOfPlayers;
        int i,j;
        char** players = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char**)*numOfPlayers); // players array
        for (i=0 ; i<numOfPlayers ; i++){
                players[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10); // each player 1st D array
        }
        for (i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
                for (j=0 ; j<10 ; j++){
                        players[i][j] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);      
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Allocation in your code is wrong!

Do like this:

```
    char** players = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numOfPlayers); 
                                       ^ remove one *  
    for (i=0 ; i<numOfPlayers ; i++){
            players[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)* 10); // each player 1st D array
                                    //    ^ remove * it should be char
    }
```

note: `sizeof(char) != sizeof(char*)`.
You don't need second nested for loop too. (just above code is fine)
[Also avoid casting return value from malloc/calloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

**Note** A mistake in your code is that  `numOfPlayers` is not  initialized (you are trying with garbage value).

Comment:

> But then, i only have 2D array. i need an array that each cell of him points to a 2D array like so... you misunderstood my question

Read if you wants - a [matrix of String or/ 3D char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522035/allocate-memory-to-char-in-c/16522223#16522223)

To allocate a matrix like: `players[playerNum][Row][Col]`

```
char ***players;
players = calloc(playerNum, sizeof(char**)); 
for(z = 0; z < playerNum; z++) { 
    players[z] = calloc(Row, sizeof(char*));
    for(r = 0; r < Row; r++) {
        players[z][r] = calloc(Col, sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

**Edit** If you wants to allocate continues memory for data, then you can use following technique. It will also be preferable because it makes less call of malloc function.

```
char *players_data,  // pointer to char 
     ***players; // pointer to 2D char array
players_data = calloc(playerNum * Row * Col, sizeof(char)); //1 memory for elements 
players = calloc(playerNum, sizeof(char **)); //2 memory for addresses of 2D matrices 
for(i = 0; i < playerNum; i++){
  players[i] = calloc(Row, sizeof(char*)); //3 memory for data cols
  for(r = 0; r < Row; r++){ //4  Distributed memory among rows
     players[i][r] = players_data + (i * Row * Col) + (r * Col);
  }
}
```

A good reference to learn: [Dynamic Three Dimensional Arrays in C\C++](http://mycodelog.com/2010/05/21/array3d/)

Comment: thaks for your answer. Can you explain me why the * need to be removed?

Comment: @user2216190 because you need to allocate memory for that type of values you wants to store. In `players`  you wants to store addresses of char = so just `char*`, In `players[i]` you wants to store values `char`

Comment: @user2216190 that is because `numOfPlayers` value not assigned

Comment: the numOfPlayers is initialized, and it still fails. thnaks for you help so far.

Comment: @user2216190 you didn't read answer correctly I said *`You don't need second nested for loop too. (just above code is fine)`*

Comment: But then, I only have 2D array. I need an array that each cell of him points to a 2D array like so... you misunderstood my question :)

Comment: Each player has 10X10 array , and there is an array that points to each player...