# C: passing an array (pointer) to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference

I have a function I would like to have a function to receive a 2D array (H), to read a specified column (col) and to pass it to another array (b).
It appears that the code below is not OK has I was expecting to get a 1 printed.
Any guidance is very much appreciated.

```
#define nline 5
#define ncol 4

#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void count0(int **M,int col, int *a);

void main(){

    int i;     
    int **H;

    H=(int**)malloc(nline*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<nline;i++){
        H[i]=(int*)malloc(ncol*sizeof(int));
    }

    H[0][0]=8;
    H[0][1]=5;
    H[0][2]=6;
    H[0][3]=0;
    H[1][0]=7;
    H[1][1]=5;
    H[1][2]=4;
    H[1][3]=0;
    H[2][0]=5;
    H[2][1]=1;
    H[2][2]=1;
    H[2][3]=7;
    H[3][0]=0;
    H[3][1]=0;
    H[3][2]=0;
    H[3][3]=2;
    H[4][0]=1;
    H[4][1]=0;
    H[4][2]=1;
    H[4][3]=4;

    int *b;

    int col=1;

    count0(H,col,&b); 

    printf("num 0=%d\n",b[2]); getchar();

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void count0(int **M,int col, int *a){

    int i;

    a=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<nline;i++){
        a[i]=M[i][col];
        a=realloc(a,(i+2)*sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: do `type *var = malloc(size * sizeof(*var));` it's less verbose, and you don't repeat the `type` three times.

Comment: `void count0(int **M,int col, int *a){` should be `void count0(int **M,int col, int **a){`

Comment: In C, you don't cast from `void *` to other pointer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already knows the number of rows = `nline` in your matrix in count0 function. So you should simply allocate all memory for array `a` in count function one time, you don't need to re-call realloc() function.

```
void count0(int **M, int col, int** a){
   (*a) = malloc(nline * sizeof(int));
   for(i = 0; i < nline; i++){ 
      (*a)[i] = M[i][col];
   }
}
```

Note: precedence of `[]` is higher then `*` so you need `()` around `*a`

just call this function as: `count0(H, col, &b);`

and `free(b);` in main() after printf statement to deallocate memory explicitly.

Comment: Thks! And if instead of a be an 1D array it was a 2D array? A triple pointer would needed to be defined in the function arguments int*** a?

Comment: @user16720 yes! and Check this answer: [Allocate memory 2d array in function C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062718/allocate-memory-2d-array-in-function-c?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @user16720 if you wants to [allocate memory for 3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761205/dynamic-pointing-array-to-a-dynamic-2-dimensions-array/17761224#17761224)

Answer (score 2):

Your argument for the output `b` is wrong. It needs to be a pointer to a pointer (like how you pass it). Right now you should get a compiler warning about it. The function prototype should be

```
void count0(int **M,int col, int **a);
```

Then in the function you need to use the dereference operator to access `a`:

```
*a = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
```

Note that I don't cast the return value of `malloc`, there no need to and neither should you.

Comment: Thks! And if instead of a be an 1D array it was a 2D array? A triple pointer would needed to be defined in the function arguments int*** a?

Comment: @user16720 It all depends on how you declare the variable you pass into the function, but if you do it like `H` (the `M` argument in `count0`) then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have this variable:

```
int * b;
```

Point to an newly allocated array after this call:

```
count0(H,col,&b);
```

To do this, you must change the signature of count 0 to the following:

```
void count0(int **M,int col, int **a);
```

Note that int *a is now int **a. Then in the body of count0, you must use the following lines to allocate/reallocate a:

```
*a=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
*a=realloc(a,(i+2)*sizeof(int));
```

Right now, `a` is a pointer variable that only exists in the scope of `count0`. Initially its value is `&b` (which right now doesn't make sense since `&b` is an `int**`, and `a` is an `int*`). You have `a` point to newly allocated memory, which is lost after the function. The changes I suggest will have `*a`, and therefore `b`, to point to memory that can be retrieved after the function call.

Comment: Thks! And if instead of a be an 1D array it was a 2D array? A triple pointer would needed to be defined in the function arguments int*** a?

Comment: It depends what you want to do! If you want to allocate space for the "rows" of this 2D array, as you do earlier with `H=(int**)malloc(nline*sizeof(int*));`, then yes. You would pass `int *** a`, and call `&a = (int**)malloc(nline*sizeof(int*));`. Assuming you have already done this, and you want to allocate "columns", as you do earlier in the program with `H[i]=(int*)malloc(ncol*sizeof(int));`, you would be able to still pass `int ** a` and simply call `a[i] = (int*)malloc(ncol*sizeof(int));` . That is because `a[i]` will already reference space for a int pointer.