# Reference to a pointer is lost

Tags: c

I am trying to understand why this statement doesn't work.

```
char resp[] = "123456789";
void getValue(char *im)
{
   im = resp;
   printf("\n%s\n",im);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char imei[11] = {0};
    getValue(imei);
    printf("\nIMEI: %s\n",imei);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123456789
IMEI:
```

Comment: You need to read a basic C tutorial. ***URGENT***

Comment: here is [need of pointer to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306935/need-of-pointer-to-pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not assign with `=`, use `strcpy` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char resp[] = "123456789";
void getValue(char *im)
{
   im = strcpy(im, resp);
   printf("\n%s\n",im);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char imei[11] = {0};
    getValue(imei);
    printf("\nIMEI: %s\n",imei);
    return 0;
}
```

That's because `imei` is an array[11] (not just a pointer to), if you want to assign via `=` you can:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char resp[] = "123456789";
void getValue(char **im)
{
   *im = resp;
   printf("\n%s\n",*im);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *imei; /* Not an array but a pointer */
    getValue(&imei);
    printf("\nIMEI: %s\n",imei);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be worthwhile to explain the reason instead of just spoon-feeding OP with the ready-made "gimme teh codez".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I just need to know why doesn't this value reflect after the function.

Comment: H2CO3, you are right, I will try, but my english is not so good ;)

Answer (score 2):

C passes parameters by value. Whatever change you ale to the `im` will be lost when the function exits. If you want to preserve the change. Pass the address of the pointer. Then you can change the pointer at the address you pass.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but isn't the array always passed as reference?

Comment: This is exactly the point I was trying to make.  Caleb and Alter Man are correct: 1) If you want to copy the contents of resp into imei, the use `strcpy()`.  2) If you want to make imei point to resp, then you must use `getValue(char **im)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char resp[] = "123456789";

void getValue(char **im)
{
   *im = resp;
   printf("\n%s\n",*im);
}
```

You need to pass a *pointer to a pointer* as your program argument.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it was the questioners intent. He allocated space to hold the copied string in imei.