# Printing array of chars using pointer to char

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have a question regarding pointers. When I iterate through a char array using pointer to char array in function, original array stays the same, but when I do it in main function, I can't print char array.

**I am new to pointers.**

```
void f(char* a)
{
    while (*a!=0) {
    *(a++); // going through array
    }
}
int main()
{
    char* a1 = "test";
    f(a1);
    cout <<a1<<endl; // I can normally print out "test"
    return 0;
}
```

But,

```
int main()
{
    char* a1 = "test";
    while (*a1!=0) {
    *(a1++);
    }
    cout <<a1<<endl; // won't print anything
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, even though I am passing pointer to function, why is original array not modified?

Comment: Same reason an `int` isn't modified when you pass a copy of it to a function.

Comment: here you [Need of Pointer to Pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306935/need-of-pointer-to-pointer/18307020#18307020)

Answer (score 5):

Since you're incrementing the pointer `a1`, it points to the character '\0' at the end of the loop in `main`. Printing a null character prints nothing (empty string).

When you do this with a function, the pointer `a` is local is local to the function. It is modified within the function but is not changed in `main`. If you wanted similar results between the two examples, you would have to change the function to accept a reference parameter to the pointer:

```
void f(char * &a) { . . . }
```

Answer (score 3):

`f(a1);`

won't modify your `a1` after `f` exits

However

```
while (*a1!=0) {
    *(a1++);
    }
```

before `cout`

will make `a1` to point to null character, so nothing gets printed

Comment: In this case, yes. But if `f` takes its parameter by reference, then it would be different...

Answer (score 3):

you're not changing `a1` when you call your function.  you're only changeing a copy of `a1` that is passed into that function: `a`

But when you call `a1++` in your main function, you are changing `a1` and when it's finished, `a1` will be `0` or `'\0'`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in second case,`a1` is pointing to `\0` character after the loop exists. To see the same result in case of 1, receive pointer by reference.

```
void f(char* & a); // Valid in C++ only
```

Comment: @user2648841: but it won't be the "same"; you would have to explicitly take the address before passing, and explicitly dereference it before using it in the function.

Answer (score 2):

The array `a1` exists while the function main() is still active.
The address of `a1` is passed to the function.
Such address is reserved to `a1` because `main()` is still active.
Now, the variable `a` is a pointer whose initial value is a copy of `a1`, in the moment you do the call `f(a1)`.

Take in account that `a` is a variable, and behaves like int, char, float, etc.
So, if you modify its "value" (that is, in this case, the memory address that `a` points to), the original address of `a1` keeps untouched.

However, if you modify a member of `a` inside f():

```
  a[0] = '!';
```

then the original array becomes: `a1` equals to `"!est"`.
The reason is that you are changing the content of the character held in the address of `a` (plus 0), which is (at the very start of execution of `f()`) the content of the address of `a1` (plus 0).

Answer (score 1):

Read more about pointers [here](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/languages/jsw_tut_pointers.aspx)

To be able to print the string in your second case, do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char* a1 = "test";
    char *ptr = a1; //create another pointer to a1
    while (*ptr != 0) cout << *ptr++;
    cout << endl << a1 << endl;
    //You should get an output of the same string on 2 lines
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The formal parameter `a` in `f` is a different object in memory from the actual parameter `a1` in `main`, so changing the value of `a` does not affect `a1`.

To mimic the behavior of the second snippet, you would have to pass a pointer to `a1`, like so:

```
void f( char **a )
{
  while ( **a != 0 )
    (*a)++;  // increment the thing a points to
}

int main( void )
{
  char *a1 = "test";
  f( &a1 );  // pass a pointer to a1
  cout << a1 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In this code, we don't pass the value stored in `a1` to `f`, we pass the *address* of `a1`.  In `f`, we don't write to `a`, we write to `*a`, or what `a` points to.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **pass-by-value**. (Everything in C++ is pass-by-value unless the function parameter is a reference type, i.e. has `&`, in which case it would be pass-by-reference.)

In pass-by-value, assignments to a parameter (and `++` is an assignment) do not have any effect on things outside the function.