# Keep segfaulting when trying to pass struct into function

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to pass a pointer to a queue into the createQueue function:

```
void createQueue(struct pqueue *queue){
    queue = malloc( sizeof(struct pqueue) );  
    queue->root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    queue->root->next = 0;   
    queue->root->taskID = 12;
    queue->root->priority = 5000;
}
```

I also try to add to the newly created queue like this:

```
void add(struct pqueue *queue, int taskID, int priority){
struct node *conductor;
conductor = queue->root;
if ( conductor != 0 ) {
        while ( conductor->next != 0)
        {
                conductor = conductor->next;
        }
}
 conductor->next = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  
 conductor = conductor->next;
 if ( conductor == 0 )
  {
      printf( "Out of memory" );
  }
  /* initialize the new memory */
  conductor->next = 0;         
  conductor->taskID = taskID;
  conductor->priority = priority;
}
```

from the main function:

```
int main()
{
    struct pqueue *queue;       

    createQueue(queue);
    add(queue, 234093, 9332);
}
```

...but I keep segfaulting.  Any reason why this keeps happening?

EDIT:

The structs for pqueue and node are like this:

```
struct node {
  int taskID;
  int priority;
  struct node *next;
};

struct pqueue{
  struct node *root;
};
```

Comment: You  [Need of Pointer to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306935/need-of-pointer-to-pointer/18307020#18307020)

Comment: What do `pqueue` and `node` look like?

Comment: `queue = malloc( sizeof(struct pqueue) ); ` You are assigning to a local variable. The calle wont see. Put the malloc in the caller and you'll be Ok. Also you could make the created queue the **return value** of the function, instead of the useless `void()`

Comment: Is that all the code required to seg fault or are you seg faulting after `createQueue` when you attempt to use `queue`?

Comment: Literally the same question was asked yesterday with a different function name and struct tag.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Investigating right now.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour how do I pass in the queue to the createQueue function then?

Comment: See @GrijeshChauhan comment at the top or the answer below, please in the future always provide an SSCCE, it will prevent us guessing what the problem really is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, everything is passed by value. Therefore, when you call `createQueue(queue)`, you are passing a **copy** of the pointer to the function. Then, inside the function, when you say `queue = malloc(...)`, you are setting that **copy** of the pointer equal to your newly allocated memory - leaving `main()`'s copy of that pointer unchanged.

You want to do something like this:

```
void createQueue(struct pqueue **queue)
{
    (*queue) = malloc( ... );
}

int main(void)
{
    struct pqueue *queue;

    createQueue(&queue);
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306935/need-of-pointer-to-pointer/18307020#18307020) has a more detailed description of what's going wrong for you.

Comment: I was going to do that earlier, but stackoverflow said I had to wait a few minutes.  Ughh...