# Binary search tree insertion - root always null

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, insertion

I have ds code for inserting values in a binary search tree using recursion. The problem is that the root always remains null.
Upon execution, the 1st printf() prints 10 but the 2nd printf (after insertRec(10)) does not print anything as root is null.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct llist
{
       int data;           
      struct llist *left;
      struct llist *right;       
};
typedef struct llist node;

void insertRec(node *r, int num)
{   
     if(r==NULL)
     {      
             r=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); 
             r->data=num; 
             r->left=NULL; 
             r->right=NULL; printf("%d ",r->data); //1st printf

     }     
     else
     {
         if(num < r->data)
           insertRec(r->left, num);             
         else
           insertRec(r->right, num);                 
     }         
}    
void display(node *x)
{          
     if(x != NULL)
     {
       display(x->left);
       printf("%d-->",x->data);
       display(x->right);        
     }
     else 
     return;              
}
int main()
{  
    node *root=NULL; 
        insertRec(root,10);  
        if(root !=NULL)  
            printf("\ndata=%d",root->data); //2nd printf
        insertRec(root,5);
        insertRec(root,15);
        insertRec(root,3);
        insertRec(root,18); 
        display(root);
        getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `root` as value so changes made to `root` in insert function doesn't reflect at main function, hence `root` remains NULL in main function. To rectify your code, you [need to pass Pointer to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306935/need-of-pointer-to-pointer/18307020#18307020).  Pass  address of `root` to reflect change in main function.

```
void insertRec(node *r, int num)
```

should be coded like:

```
void insertRec(node **r, int num)
{
    if(*r==NULL)
    {      
         *r= malloc(sizeof(node)); 
         (*r)->data=num; 

 //
```

and use `*root` inside insert function.

And call it as `insertRec(&root, 10);` from main.

Additionally,  if you allocates memory dynamically then you should free allocated memory using free  explicitly.

One more thing learn [Indenting C Programs](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html).