# Why this segfault in c program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Can't understand why this segfault in c, valgrind said the fault is at line 25.
It is a program to manage a medical studio, when e==1 a patient arrives so it must be added to the queue, e==2 a patient is visited so the first element in queue must be deleted, when e==0 the studio close and the program must print the list of patients remained in alphabetical order and the $.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN (101)

typedef struct _item {
  char *name;
  struct _item *next;
} item;

void insert(item* tail, item* next){
  item* new = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item));
  new->name = (char*)malloc(MAXLEN*sizeof(char));
  new->next = NULL;
  scanf("%s", new->name);
  if (tail == NULL){
    tail = new;
    next = tail;
  }
  else
    next->next = new;
}

void examination(item *tail){
  item *patient;
  if (tail->next == NULL)
    tail=NULL;
  else{
    patient = tail;
    tail = tail->next;
    free(patient);
  }
}

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
  return strcmp(*((char**)a) , *((char**)b));
}

int main(){
  int e=1, counter=0, i=0;
  item *tail = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item));
  item *next;
  char **remained;
  tail = NULL;
  next = tail;

  while (e != 0){
    scanf("%d", &e);
    switch (e){
    case 1:
      insert(tail, next);
      break;
    case 2:
      examination(tail);
    case 0:
      break;
    default:
      return 1;
    }
  } 
  next = tail;
  while (next != NULL){
    counter ++;
    next = next->next;
  }
  next = tail;
  remained = (char**)malloc(counter*sizeof(char*));
  while(i < counter){
    remained[i] = next->name;
     next = next->next;
    i++;
  }
  qsort(remained, counter, sizeof(item), cmp);
  next = tail;
  while (next != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", next->name);
    next = next->next;
  }
  printf("$\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: insert function seems wrong you [need of Pointer to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18307020/1673391)

Comment: And line 25 is which line, please?

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (tail->next == NULL)
```

The `tail->next` passed to `examination()` is uninitialized because `insert()` you are passing the pointer by value and not by reference nor returning the pointer from `insert()` so basically `tail` is allocated memory but the members are not initialized and you are trying to access them which will lead to undefined behavior and hence the crash.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan As part of my answer I say `tail` members need to be initialized and also have given 2 ways to do it. One Have a pointer to pointer as a argument and another do all the operation within `insert()` and return a pointer of type `item`